# $X$ coherent with family $\mathcal{B}$ of subspaces.Then $\bigsqcup_{B\in\mathcal{B}} B\to X$ induced by inclusion of each $B\to X$ is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology

> Proposition $5.2 \ (b)$: Suppose $X$ s a topological space whose topology is coherent with a family $\mathcal{B}$ of subspaces.
>
> Then the map $\bigsqcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B \to X$ induced by the inclusion of each set $B \to X$ is a quotient map

(This is proposition 5.2 (b) in *Introduction to Topological Manifolds by Lee*)

What does this mean rigorously? I'm having a hard time trying to unwind exactly what the author is trying to say.

What I think the author is trying to say is that the map $f : \bigsqcup_{\alpha \in \mathcal{A}} B_{\alpha} \to X$ defined by $f(x, \alpha) = x$ where $\alpha \in A$ for some indexing set $A$ which is bijective with $\mathcal{B}$ (the reason for this is that $\bigsqcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B$ is then isomorphic to $\bigsqcup_{\alpha \in A} B_{\alpha}$ in the category of sets) is a quotient map.

Am I correct? Because $\bigsqcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B \to X$ isn't even defined because $\mathcal{B}$ is a family of subspaces (and hence sets) but it is not an *indexed* family of subspaces (and therefore not an indexed family of sets) so we can't form the abstract (set-theoretic) disjoint union.

Comment: Why couldn't you form the disjoint union ? It's indexed by itself, with the identity map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing yourself over a small notational issue.

> Then the map $f \colon \bigsqcup_{B \in \mathcal B} B \to X$ induced by the inclusion of each set $B \to X$ is a quotient map.

Define the disjoint union to be

$$\bigsqcup_{B \in \mathcal B} B = \{ x_B \mid x \in B \text{ for some } B \in \mathcal B \}.$$

The points in the disjoint union thus "remember" what set in $\mathcal B$ they came from. A single point $x \in X$ now has a copy of itself in the disjoint union for each set $B \in \mathcal B$ in which it appears. The map $f$ identifies all these points again, taking $x_B$ to $x$. (That is, if $x \in B \cap B'$ for $B, B' \subset X$, then $f (x_B) = f (x_{B'}) = x$.)

Comment: Hmmmm I want to accept this definition of the disjoint union, but the usual definition I'm used to with disjoint unions is the following, let $\{B_i\}_{i \in I}$ be an indexed family of sets, then the disjoint union is defined as $$\bigsqcup_{i \in I}B_i = \{(x, i) \ |\ x \in B_i \ \text{ and } \  i \in I\} $$ so we have ordered pairs in the disjoint union. The reason why I'd prefer this is because (I think) it simplifies some of the topological properties. So is there any way to formulate what you've said above into an 'ordered pair' definition like the one above?

Comment: Of course. The simplest modification would be to write $(x,B)$ where I wrote $x_B$. (This is what is meant by "indexed by itself" in Eric Wofsey's answer — you can take the index set to be $\mathcal B$ itself.)

Comment: But $B$ is a set, which was the only thing stopping me from writing $(x, B)$ that in the first place, does $B$ being a set change anything?

Comment: No, it doesn't change much. You only want to make sure that the second entry of $(x, B)$ uniquely identifies $B$ as a set. Whether you think of $B$ *as a (unique) set* or *as a (unique) symbol denoting a (unique) set* doesn't matter here (and at least as a symbol it should correspond to your idea of an index).

Comment: Thank you for the accept mark and bounty. I hope it's all clear to you now!

Comment: Thank you for all the help, it is clear to me now!

Answer (score 1):

This means what you think it means.  There is not actually any abuse of notation here, though.  It is completely standard to write something like $$\bigsqcup_{i\in I}f(i)$$ where $f$ is some function that takes an element $i\in I$ and outputs a set $f(i)$.  The indexed family you are taking the disjoint union of here is $(f(i))_{i\in I}$.  In the case of $$\bigsqcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}} B,$$ $I=\mathcal{B}$ and $f$ is the identity function, so $f(B)$ is just $B$.  In other words, this family *is* indexed, namely by the identity map $\mathcal{B}\to\mathcal{B}$.